# How to make iPhone app smaller on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have converted ILColorPicker to work on XCode4 and Storyboard.  My problem is that it fills the entire UIView on the iPad... where do I start looking for a way to make it smaller?

I was thinking of using a subview, but not sure how to "wire" it into the subview.  Any other ideas?

UPDATE:  here is the code where I believe I can modify the frame, except I don't know how...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using applicationWillAppear, and setting the scale through it?

Comment: no, can't say I have... just did a google on it, and there is nothing... where do I find out the specs for it?

Comment: Sorry. I meant viewWillAppear. Search for applicationDidLoad too. viewWillAppear is better though.

And these are delegate methods.

Comment: Check http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%207.pdf page 5, that would clarify what I mean, if I didn't misunderstand what you're saying.

Comment: I have found the area where the frame is initialized (I put in a NSLog and it does get executed)... see UPDATE above...question now is: how do I change this code to make the frame smaller and give it a starting position?

Comment: Are you trying to run it in the iPhone emulator on the iPad, or just trying to fill less of the UIWindow?

Comment: Moshe:  I am trying to run the ILColorPicker on the iPad, with iPhone size, i.e. fill less of the window (see UPDATE above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the frame size is programmed with `CGRectMake` like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the above the variable `x` and `y` corrispond to the top-left corner. And `width` and `height` are the width and height of the frame.

Comment: Gavin... we're getting closer... thank you... apparently there are other places that initialize the frame also, so will have to look for them... thank you...